# How to get conditional formatting to use the cell date value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I set up conditional formatting with the goal of checking cell dates. The formatting is supposed to gauge and show how quickly a date is coming up to complete a task.

Below is how I set this up. What I did was use `TODAY()` thinking that would pull the cell value. What it is doing is using the current date instead of the cell date. How do I use the cell's date instead?

You can see from the green outlined cells a specific date and then the other green outline represents the date ranges I am after. The 6/3/2021 date should not have any highlighting at all since the date passed.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to *Home>Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cells Rules>More Rules* to select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Then enter the following formulas in sequence and select the corresponding cell format.

```
=AND($B12-C12>=21,$B12-C12<=37)
=AND($B12-C12>=8,$B12-C12<=20)
=AND($B12-C12>=0,$B12-C12<=7)
=AND(C12-$B12>=1,C12-$B12<=7)
```

[image]

Update:
[image]

Comment: Hi, if you have a chance to check this issue, please check whether my answer is helpful.

Comment: Hi. I am really looking for the cell values to be treated as dates. If the cell value of B12 is 6/3, how does that compare to today. Are we x days before or after.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question now, in your example, which date do you want to compare the date in column I with?
In my example, I compare columns C and D with column B and get the result in the image above.
Regarding the comparison between 6/3 and the current date (TODAY()), I have updated my answer, please check it out.